# How to count the number of consecutive occurrences of a value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, I was trying to calculate how many time that True occurs consecutively.

(eg. True, True, True  indicates 2 consecutive occurrences)

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True]})
```

output:

```
6
```

I really don't know how to solve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
grp = (~df['A']).cumsum()
df['A'].groupby(grp).sum().sub(1).clip(0,).sum()
```

Output:

```
6
```

Create groupings of all true values using cumsum on False values, then sum the True values in each group subtract 1 for the first False that defines the group.  Use clip to eliminate groups that have no True and sum those values.

---

Here's another way broken down in steps via dataframe columns.

```
df['B'] = (~df['A']).cumsum()
df['C'] = df.duplicated(['A', 'B'], keep='first')
df['C'].sum()
```

Output:

```
6
```

Detailed output:

```
        A  B      C
0   False  1  False
1   False  2  False
2    True  2  False
3    True  2   True
4   False  3  False
5    True  3  False
6   False  4  False
7   False  5  False
8   False  6  False
9   False  7  False
10   True  7  False
11   True  7   True
12   True  7   True
13   True  7   True
14  False  8  False
15   True  8  False
16   True  8   True
17   True  8   True
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your definition of consecutive is "a `True` that is preceded by a `True`", a very simple approach is to just compare the column to its shifted self, then `sum`:

```
(df['A']&df['A'].shift(fill_value=False)).sum()
```

Output: `6`

Intermediates:

```
        A  shift  A & shift
0   False  False      False
1   False  False      False
2    True  False      False
3    True   True       True # 1
4   False   True      False
5    True  False      False
6   False   True      False
7   False  False      False
8   False  False      False
9   False  False      False
10   True  False      False
11   True   True       True # 2
12   True   True       True # 3
13   True   True       True # 4
14  False   True      False
15   True  False      False
16   True   True       True # 5
17   True   True       True # 6
```

Comment: nice, or similarly something like this: `df.A.shift().add(df.A).eq(2).sum()`

Comment: @tdy yes, but I would bet that pure boolean operations are more efficient. The `sum` would however be a nice way to generalize to count rows with at least N previous `True` ;)

Comment: Wow.  Yep, that is a much more simple way of doing this calculation.  Thanks, @mozway for having a *different* look at the problem.